# Meaning of the word "FINE" in "100% FINE JAMAICAN RUM"

Tags: word-usage

If a label says:

> 100% FINE JAMAICAN RUM

What sense the word "FINE" is used here?

Comment: [Fine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine), definition 1a: free from impurity.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it's a subjective statement of quality.

> fine (adj.)
>
> mid-13c., "unblemished, **refined, pure, free of impurities**," also "**of high quality**, choice," from Old French fin "perfected, of highest quality"

Although relating to wine rather than rum (the vocabularies do share a lot of terminology), Clive Coates, a British wine critic and Master of Wine, uses the verbal categories *Very good*, *Fine*, *Very fine* and *Grand Vin* to distinguish the level of quality. Others have [written](http://www.wineanorak.com/nickfine.htm) about [the topic](http://wine.lovetoknow.com/wiki/Fine_Wine%20) too, and the [consensus](http://www.wsjwine.com/jsp/aboutwine/common/helpfulhintstemplate.jsp?hintId=100008&hhtitle=Fine%20Wines%20) seems to be that it's mostly arbitrary, and often related to price, but that the finer a wine (or other beverage), the higher quality it is.